# Reading a CSV in Python where input lines are split

Tags: python, csv

I have a kind of CSV file where the input for one logical line may be split over multiple physical lines.

Data example:

```
":T1","A1","B1","C1"
":T2","A2","B2","C2",
"D2","E2"
":T3","A3","B3","C3",
"D3"
":T4","A4"
```

This is four logical lines, with the continuation denoted by the trailing comma on the end of lines which split.

I tried to use the csv module in python:

```
import csv
with open('2.dat','r') as csvfile:
        datreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',' , quotechar='"')
        for row in datreader:
                print (', '.join(row))
                print ("*******************************")
```

Which gives:

```
:T1, A1, B1, C1
*******************************
:T2, A2, B2, C2,
*******************************
D2, E2
*******************************
:T3, A3, B3, C3,
*******************************
D3
*******************************
:T4, A4
*******************************
```

What I'd like:

```
:T1, A1, B1, C1
*******************************
:T2, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2
*******************************
:T3, A3, B3, C3, D3
*******************************
:T4, A4
*******************************
```

I'm unsure of the best way to use csv module to parse this data correctly. Input data set could be millions of rows.

Comment: you should have mentioned that each logical line should start with `:T<number>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    rows = []

    for row in reader:
        current_row = []
        if row[0].startswith(':'):
            current_row.append(row)
            rows.append(current_row)
        else:
            rows[-1].append(row)

    for row in rows:
        print(', '.join(y for x in row for y in x if y))
```

---

```
:T1, A1, B1, C1
:T2, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2
:T3, A3, B3, C3, D3
:T4, A4
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is first correct your file to match the CSV standard and then parse it.

Based on your trial data:

```
data = """
":T1","A1","B1","C1"
":T2","A2","B2","C2",
"D2","E2"
":T3","A3","B3","C3",
"D3"
":T4","A4"
""".strip('\n')
```

A simple regexp can merge split lines:

```
import re
parsed = re.sub(r',\n', ",", data)
print(parsed)
```

It returns:

```
":T4","A4"
":T1","A1","B1","C1"
":T2","A2","B2","C2","D2","E2"
":T3","A3","B3","C3","D3"
":T4","A4"
```

Which complies with CSV standard and can be easily parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Another "game" with `end` param of `print` function:

```
import csv

with open('.2dat', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i,r in enumerate(reader):
        if r[0].startswith(':T'):
            if i > 0: print('\n','*'*30, sep='')
            print(', '.join(r), end='')
        else:
            print(', '.join(r), end='')
```

The output:

```
:T1, A1, B1, C1
******************************
:T2, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2
******************************
:T3, A3, B3, C3, D3
******************************
:T4, A4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a magical CSV parser that will do exactly what you want. You'll have to do a very small amount of work yourself.

Make an new empty list of lines. Loop through the lines in `datreader`. If a line starts with `:`, append it to the new list. If it doesn't, concatenate it with the last line in the new list.